# Firebase Anonymous authentication and Device ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Does Firebase consider the **device id** when generating an anonymous token?

If uninstall the app and reinstall it, do I get the same anonymous token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UID of a user is not based on the device. If you uninstall the app, the app data will be wiped. If you then reinstall the app, and create a new user, they'll get a new UID.

Comment: Without uninstalling the app, with updating for example, will we get same uid for anonymous login every time?